# $a$ and $b$ irreducible polynomials such that $\forall u \in \mathbb{Q}[t], a|u(t^n)\iff b|u(t^n)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, irreducible-polynomials

A little  context is in order.
I was trying to find counter-examples to the following statement:

$$\phi : X\rightarrow Y \;\text{injective} 
 \Rightarrow \phi\otimes K : X\otimes_k K \rightarrow Y\otimes_k K 
\;\text{injective}$$

where $X$ and $Y$ are schemes over a field $k$ and $K/k$ is a field extension.
Here, when I say injective I mean on the topological spaces $|X|$ and $|Y|$.
Now I know this isn't true since we have the clear counter-example:
$X=\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$, $Y=\text{Spec}(\mathbb{R})$, $k=\mathbb{R}$ and 
$K=\mathbb{C}$.

Now I want to clearify that I just started studying scheme theory and one of my teachers sent me another counter-example with a more "geometric" feel to it.
We take $k=\mathbb{Q}$ the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1 _{\mathbb{Q}}$ and we look at the algebra morphism given by

$$\mathbb{Q}[t]\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[t],\quad t\mapsto t^n$$

where $n$ is odd and different from 1.
Now the fact which isn't clear for me is injectivity, my teacher says it comes from the following fact:

Let $a$ and $b$ be two irreducible monic polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[t]$, then
$$\forall u\in \mathbb{Q}[t],\{a|u(t^n)\iff b|u(t^n)\}\Rightarrow a=b$$

I have no clue how to show this fact. If this is true however, we can consider 
$\zeta_n$ a $n$ primitive root of unity and take $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$.

Thank you for any clues or answers.

Comment: Is it injective? Try $n=3$. Where do the prime ideals generated by $t-1$ and $t^2+t+1$ go?